# Python - Getting the last frame of a h264 video file

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to save the last frame of a video file to disk. The code gives no erros, but the frame saved is not the last frame. It is probably the first. I've tried different cap.set parameters, but the saved frame stays the same.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('temp.h264')

cap.set(1, cap.get(7)-1) 
#sets position to the last frame

ret, img = cap.read()
cap.release()

image = Image.fromarray(img)
image.save('tempimg.jpg')
```

Can someone tell me why this isn't working and what would be a working solution to this? Thank you.

EDIT:

I got the cap.set working after I converted the source file to mp4, using mp4box. BUT that doesn't really solve my problem because there is no time for this conversion when the code is running. The video file is a recording from picamera and to my understanding that can only do h264.

So, is there a way to get the last frame of h264?
or
Record to avi or mp4 directly using picamera?

Comment: `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)-1)`

Comment: print cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
print cap.get(7) 


both give the same -9.22337203685e+18 as value.

Comment: Try this `.h264` file for testing: https://cdn.online-convert.com/example-file/video/h264/example.h264. It this works then something is wrong with your file.

Comment: Alright, interesting. The code works with that file. So what is different with your file and h264 files recorded with picamera?

Comment: I don't know if you're using `gstreamer` API or `ffmpeg`. For testing do the following: 1. Read 1 frame with `cap.read()` outside the `while` loop. 2. Then `print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))`. See if you get any results.

Comment: Ok, I tried that. The result is the same -9.22337203685e+18 for the frame count. Interestingly I noticed that every cap.read() moves the position one frame onwards, but cap.set("with any value") moves the position back to 0.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong property index. It should be `cap.set(1, cap.get(7)-1)`. Or I think `cap.set(2, 1)`. See [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I actually had tried that earlier. I wasn't sure was it 0 or 1 based index. I edited the correction to the code now, but the problem persists.

Comment: I would suggest to use the consts variables, it is less prone to error (look at @Zindarod comment)

Comment: Tried that too, but the position doesn't seem to change. Is it possible that cv2.Videocapture doesn't like h264?

Comment: @OlliJJJ Have you tried to loop through all the frames and visualize them e.g. with `cv2.imshow` to see VideoCapture can handle h264?

Comment: Yes. I was able to loop through all the frames with cv2.imshow, but the cap.set nor cap.get aren't working.